# how to search for series of strings in a sentence in Swift 5

Tags: swift

I have an ArrayList of items. Each item has long strings for example ("The cat is in the hat","It's warm outside","It's cold outside")

what I am trying to do is search for a series of strings for example ["I am walking outside", "It's snowy outside", "Walking in a snowy day] in any given order in the Data Struct. The strings I am looking for is ["walking outside snowy"]. It must contain all of the words. I am able to retrieve only one string. However, an array of strings I cannot accomplish it.

my data structure is

```
struct Product: Codable {
  title: String?
  otherStuff: String?
}
```

This is what I tried:

```
    let tempProducts = self.products.filter({
        $0.title?.range(of: category, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
    })
```

Comment: It's unclear. Could you give an input, search text, and why it should ke kept or not?

Comment: What I got from your statement that you want to filter an array of strings for few keywords. Like the result should contain all the strings from array if it contains any of the keyword you are searching for. Is that right ?

Comment: @NajeeburRehman Yes, I believe you go it. Basically Struct Products is an array of all those mentioned above and there are some repeating words in them. I want to be able to supply a series of strings and be able to pull all those arrays and assign them to a variable. Just like the function I supplied but it only searches for 1 word, but I need a series of words.